# Problem with plotting (resp. expanding) the Hurwitz Zeta function

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I expected the two plots to be identical. Can anyone confirm that the discrepancies show a bug?

```
b[s_, v_] := If[s == 0, 1, -s*Zeta[1 - s, v]]; 

Table[Expand[FullSimplify[b[n, x]]], {n, 1, 6}]
Plot[%, {x, -1, 3/2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]

Table[BernoulliB[n, x], {n, 1, 6}]
Plot[%, {x, -1, 3/2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

Comment: It seems that not all identical. `b[s_, v_] := If[s == 0, 1, -s*Zeta[1 - s, v]]; funs1 = 
 Table[Expand[FullSimplify[b[n, x]]], {n, 1, 6}] // 
  FunctionExpand; funs2 = 
 Table[BernoulliB[n, x], {n, 1, 6}]; Grid[{funs1, funs2}, 
 Frame -> All]`

Comment: @cvgmt Yes, but that's exactly the problem!

Comment: From the Mathematica documentation, "Zeta[s] gives the Riemann zeta function \[Zeta](s)" and "Zeta[s, a] gives the generalized Riemann zeta function \[Zeta](s, a)" and "HurwitzZeta[s, a] gives the Hurwitz zeta function \[Zeta](s, a)". `MathWorld` states that there are two different forms of the Hurwitz zeta function, one implemented as `HurwitzZeta[s, a]`,  the other as `Zeta[s, a]` and the two are identical only for `Re[a] > 0`.

Comment: @Bob, see my comment on my answer. The sentence there was taken over literally from MathWorld.

Comment: As were the statements in my comment. MathWorld is telling you that there are two conventions, it is up to you to ensure that you are using the appropriate convention (and Mathematica implementation) for your particular use.

Answer (score 2):

And the solution is: use *HurwitzZeta* instead of *Zeta*.

```
b[s_, v_] := If[s == 0, 1, -s*HurwitzZeta[1 - s, v]]; 
V := Table[FunctionExpand[FullSimplify[b[n, x]]], {n, 1, 6}];
W := Table[BernoulliB[n, x], {n, 1, 6}]; 
Grid[{V, W}, Frame -> All]
```

oh well ...

Comment: According to [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html): "The Hurwitz zeta function is implemented in the Wolfram Language as Zeta[s, a]." ??

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a partial answer:  According to [Mathworld, Eq. 9](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html), the comparison should be:

```
bs = Table[-BernoulliB[n + 1, x]/(n + 1), {n, 1, 6}]
```

and

```
zs = Table[Zeta[-n, x], {n, 1, 6}]
```

which appear to be the same when x>0:

```
Plot[bs, {x, 0, 3/2}]
```

and

```
Plot[zs, {x, 0, 3/2}]
```

but not when x < 0

```
Plot[bs, {x, -1, 0}]
```

and

```
Plot[zs, {x, -1, 0}]
```

but note that:

```
With[{abs = Abs[bs]}, Plot[abs, {x, -1, 0}]]
```

appears to be the same, but for n=1

Comment: What you say in the first part is exactly the same only with one factor shifted from one side to the other. For the second part: BernoulliB[n, x] are the functions against which the representation is to be validated, not to any others.